# Protect an excel sheet allowing the insertion of images via VBA code

Tags: vba, excel, worksheet

I'm trying to protect a WorkSheet allowing the insertion of images. Then I learned how to protect a WorkSheet with VBA code, but the WorkSheet aren't allowed to insert images.

When I manually protect the WorkSheet I discovered that if I check the option "**Modify Objects**", the WorkSheet allows the insertion of images.

Now, I'm searching about of parameters of the `Protect` method, then I have the following code:

```
With Sheets("Sheet1")
        .Protect Password:="password", DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=False, Scenarios:=False
End With
```

I assumed that the code occupies the parameter `DrawingObjects`, which should allow the insertion of images, but the code doesn't works properly, the WorkSheet is protected, but still doesn't allow the insertion of images.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe your code *protects* `DrawingObjects`, rather than allowing them to be inserted. I think it should be `DrawingObjects:=False` in order to permit this to work.

Whenever I use VBA with a protected worksheet, I first unprotect it, do whatever I want in VBA, then reapply the protection. Or at at least, remove specific protections and then reapply them.

Comment: Your're right, the parameter `DrawingObjects:=False` allow the image insertion, on the contrary, the other denies it `DrawingObjects:=True`.